# Are questions about individual medical advice on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I noticed this question which appears to be requesting personalized medical advice, almost to the point of using StackExchange as second opinion after getting unfavourable advice from a doctor.

> [Any suggestions to help someone experiencing joint pain after giving up dairy products?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/672/1236)
>
> However, over the past few weeks she has been experiencing more joint pain after her runs, and occasional muscle aches in the morning when she wakes up.
>
> She has [consulted with a doctor about this], but it was not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, these questions need to be closed.**

At first take it seems like maybe this kind of question should be migrated to [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/), but if you're familiar with their site you know this is exactly the kind of question they *hate*. They have this giant yellow banner posted on the right-hand sidebar.

> Health Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is **not intended as a substitute for individualized diagnosis and treatment** by a qualified healthcare provider.

They've put a lot of work into developing their disclaimer, including [consulting with Stack Overflow's lawyers](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/health-se-disclaimer). We haven't even done that much, so it seems like allowing requests for individualized health advice on this site would be hugely problematic. We can't allow requests that would be closed & deleted on Health.SE just because it might be related to vegetarianism.